# sort rows of each cell in pandas dataframe which are linked with columns

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe like below.'prof' column and 'scores' col has a relation.i.e doctor in 'prof' col has score as -2.3 ,teacher has 9.1 score and nurse has 0.5 etc.,

| val | prof | scores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | doctor,teacher,nurse | -2.3,9.1,0.5 |
| S | doctor,actor | 0.1,3 |

And what I expect as output is in sorted order of scores col ,prof column also to be adjusted

| val | prof | scores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | teacher,nurse,doctor | 9.1,0.5,-2.3 |
| S | actor,doctor | 3,0.1 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.set_index('val').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index().sort_values(by=['val','scores'],ascending=False).groupby('val',as_index=False).agg(list)
```

or

```
l = ['prof','scores']
(df[['val']].join(df[l]
.applymap(lambda x: x.split(','))
.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({i:','.join(j) for i,j in (zip(l,zip(*sorted(zip(*x),key = lambda y: y[-1],reverse = True))))}),axis=1)))
```